# What's the smallest permutation group which has a subgroup not known to be a Galois group of a polynomial over $\mathbb Q$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, galois-theory

The question of what is the group of smallest order for which the inverse Galois problem is open seems to attract more attention, for example, [this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/q/443186/210944). Apparently, the smallest order is $672$. However, by Cayley's theorem, a group of order $n$ embeds (in general) only into $S_n$. And $S_{672}$ is a truly massive group. On the other hand, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathieu_group_M23), the Mathieu group $M_{23}$ has no known representation as a Galois group. $M_{23}$ is a subgroup of $S_{23}$, which has a more manageable $23!\approx 2.5\cdot 10^{22}$ elements, less than one mole.

So it is natural to ask: is there an $n<23$ such that $S_n$ has a subgroup for which the inverse Galois problem is unsolved? That is, for which it is not know if there's a polynomial in $\mathbb Q[x]$ which has that group as its Galois group.

And yet another framing: what's the smallest degree $d$ for which we do not know what the possible Galois groups of polynomials in $\mathbb Q[x]$ of degree $d$ are?

Comment: $23!$ elements is still massive although the Monster group has much more elements.

Comment: The referenced MO thread seems to speak about not just any group of order $672$, but specifically about $PGL(2,7)$. Hence your embedding it in $S_{672}$ as if it were just a random group of same order seems a bit unfair

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen what I understood from Joachim's last comment is that the polynomial $x^8-x^7-29x^6+11x^5-139x^4+37x^3+32x^2-10x-1$ in Malle's paper has Galois group $PGL(2,7)$, and the group with smallest order for which the inverse Galois problem is unsolved is another group of order 672.